# how to detect message that has my bot username discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot react on the message which has its username

If I enter my bot username like this, it works:

```
if(message.content.includes('bot123')) console.log('TRUE') //TRUE
```

But this one doesn't:

```
if(message.content.includes(client.user.username)) console.log('TRUE') //doesn't work
```

I wonder why and if there is a way to make client.user.username works

Comment: Please add some more information, for example: how does your message looks (its content)?

Comment: Can you log `client.user.username` ? Like `console.log(client.user.username)`

Comment: @itzJOH_ I want my bot react on messages which have the bot username or mention it, like "baka bot123", "@bot123" or "bot12345".....

Comment: @Akio I can, it still prints "bot123" on the console but return nothing on message has the bot username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the messageCreate event the only parameter is message, thus if you are using a lets say command handler it would be

```
if(message.content.includes(message.client.user.username)) // ...
```